# jquery adding stripes to ul

Tags: jquery, list, css-selectors

Hi I'm trying to make a function that will add a striped effect to an unordered list, I've got the following so far but cant work out how the selector should work.

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.stripe = function(){
        this.$("li:even").css("background-color","#f00");
    };
    })(jQuery);


    $("list_id").stripe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reko has said, the best way to implement this is using the pseudo odd and even. Try implementing it the same as the following:

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.formattedList li:odd").addClass("oddItem");
    $("ul.formattedList li:even").addClass("evenItem");
}
```

**CSS**

```
.formattedList .oddItem {
    background-color: Black;
    color: White;
}

.formattedList .evenItem {
    background-color: White;
    color: Black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="formattedList">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

Lots of complicated answers using jQuery here. All you need is a small bit of CSS:

```
ul > li:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9 ;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this question was posted in 2009, and predates CSS3 selectors like `:nth-of-type` by two years.

Comment: Fair point, I just noticed that there were pretty recent answers too. Nevertheless, hopefully if somebody lands here from Google, as I just did, they'll at least have a good answer now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).children('li:even').css("background-color","#f00");
```

Comment: Also: $("list_id").stripe(); should be: $("#list_id").stripe();

Answer (score 0):

You have the call the call the children of the unorderedlist

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

### JQuery

```
(function($) {
$.fn.stripe = function(){
  $(this).children("li:even").css("background-color","#ccc");
};

$('ul').stripe();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use `nth-child` CSS3 property
Something like:

```
.black-one {
 background: black;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#list1 li:nth-child(2n+2)").addClass("black-one");
</script>
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doWyKg